# Conversion implicit

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a property of my class but I always get the same error

"user-defined cast must be cast from or to a delimiter type"

```
public class CharCashItemOutputBoxEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string RecId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string StrChargeNo { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    public string GaveCharName { get; set; }
    public int Confirm { get; set; }
    public int Period { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string EvPtype { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator long(BaseEntity baseEntity)
    {
        return baseEntity.Id;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: It's exactly what it says it is - the parameter or return type has to be `CharCashItemOutputBoxEntity`, because that's the class in which you're defining the conversion. Or you could move this conversion into `BaseEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the implicit conversion into the base class, because the source type must be the same as the class it is defined in.

For example, consider the following code with the two classes. **Each has its own implicit conversion** from the contained type.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator long(BaseEntity baseEntity)
    {
        return baseEntity.Id;
    }
}

public class CharCashItemOutputBoxEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string RecId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string StrChargeNo { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    public string GaveCharName { get; set; }
    public int Confirm { get; set; }
    public int Period { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string EvPtype { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator string(CharCashItemOutputBoxEntity entity)
    {
        return entity.RecId;
    }
}
```

with sample code

```
var entity = new CharCashItemOutputBoxEntity();

long id = entity;
string recId = entity;
```